# hyperledger fabric fabcar port 7051 error

Tags: port

I have a general error when trying to run hyperledger fabric projects: there is always some error concerning the connection to localhost:7051. For example, when running the fabcar tutorial program, I get following error:

```
2019-03-30T21:58:23.605Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpc://localhost:7051
2019-03-30T21:58:23.607Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpc://localhost:7051
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpc://localhost:7051
```

I have no idea where this comes from. To be clear, I have tried to search the internet for solutions, but they all failed to solve the problem. For example, I tried to disable my firewall with

```
sudo ufw disable,
```

but it did not change anything.

Anyone have an idea what this could be due to?